# Flutter image_picker "'PickedFile'" can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'

Tags: image, flutter, picker

I'm calling a widget in my code to display the selected image through image-picker plugin; following is my code:

```
Widget _imagePlaceHolder() {
if (imageSelected == null){
  return Text("No File Selected!!");
} else {
  Image.file(imageSelected, width: 400, height: 400);
}
```

}

but I'm getting this error:

The argument type "'PickedFile'" can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'

on imageSelected under else statement.

I'm picking an image like this from gallery:

```
Future _openGallery(BuildContext context) async {
var picture = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
this.setState(() {
  imageSelected = picture;
});}
```

I've defined:
PickedFile imageSelected;
final picker = ImagePicker();

what's going wrong here? Please help..

Answer (score 25):

`Image.file()` accepts a property of type `File` class, whereas the `ImagePicker().getImage()` method returns a type `PickedFile`.

We have to utilise the getter `.path` of the returned `PickedFile` argument and pass that file path to the create a `File` object as follows:

```
void _setImage() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
}
```

This may be done in one line as follows:

```
void _setImage() async {
    imageFile = File(await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery).then((pickedFile) => pickedFile.path));
}
```

After this, you can use the variable `imageFile` and pass it inside `Image.file()` like `Image.file(imageFile)`, or `FileImage()` like `FileImage(imageFile)` as required.

For more, see the [`image_picker` documentation on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)

Comment: This is an answer for mobile. How to do it with web?

Answer (score 2):

```
//many time when user import dart.html package than it throw error so keep note that we have to import dart.io

import 'dart.io';


final imagePicker = ImagePicker();
File imageFile;

Future getImage() async {
  var image = await imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  setState(() {
    imageFile = File(image.path);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `PickedFile imageSelected` to `File imageSelected` and use `ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)` instead of  `picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);`

Comment: still doesn't work.... if i do the suggested change then it gives error on 'picture' in my code.. the error is: A value of type 'PickedFile' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'File'.dartinvalid_assignment

Comment: You can use the classic `ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)`. i updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Morpheus answer is correct.

Just pass in the `PickedFile` variable path to `File()`.

Example:

```
final picker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';  

  var image;
      void imagem() async {
        PickedFile picked = await ImagePicker().getImage(
            preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front, source: ImageSource.camera);
        setState(() {
          image = File(picked.path);
        });
      }
```

Or case you need of code full:

```
    import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class Photos extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PhotosState createState() => _PhotosState();
}

class _PhotosState extends State<Photos> {
  var image;
  void imagem() async {
    PickedFile picked = await ImagePicker().getImage(
        preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front, source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      image = File(picked.path);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: imagem,
            child: Text("Imagem"),
          ),
          image != null ? Image.file(image) : Text("I")
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your imageFile type to PickedImage and return the file in type Casting the imageFile to File, Like:-
// Declaring the variable here

PickedImage imageFile;

And at the time of returning:-

return Image.file(File(imageFile.path),width: 400,height: 400,);

I personally faced this problem, and this solution solved it.

Comment: Please use text formatting options in StackOverflow editor. Proper formatting helps to read your answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

```
 Future pickImageFromGallery() async {
    try {
      final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery, 
      );
      setState(() {
    widget.imageFile = File(pickedFile!.path);
      });
      if (pickedFile == null) {
    throw Exception('File is not available');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```